# DataContractJsonSerializer or JsonTextWriter for arrays

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'd prefer to use Microsofts System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer
to serialize my objects in JSON so I do not have to reference any third party assemblies.

I'm trying to serialize arrays into a JSON string. There maybe just 1 array, with every other entry being the name and other being the value.
e.g.`[ "name1", "value1", "name2", "value2" ]`

I wish to serialize so that the name and value appears a pair in the JSON string
e.g.
the array in .NET is `[ "name1", "value1", "name2", "value2" ]` 
becomes

```
{
 "name1": "value1",
 "name2": "value2" 
}
```

I have successfully achieved this with the JSON.NET JsonTextWriter by looping through the 2 arrays and adding to then using the

```
jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(namesAndValues[i].ToString());
jsonWriter.WriteValue(namesAndValues[i+1]);
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with Microsofts DataContractJsonSerializer but it doesn't seem to have the same flexibility.
Is there some way?

I know I can use the JSON.NET source code itself but I'd rather use a Microsoft class if possible.

Comment: Could you include the class definition of the object which you want to serialize as `[ "name1", "value1", "name2", "value2" ]` with respect of `DataContractJsonSerializer `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataContractJsonSerializer is designed to serialise classes to JSON.  To get the kind of output you want you would have to serialise a class with 2 properties called name1 and name2 that have the values of value1 and value2.  Is the format of the JSON completely fixed, if you just want a collection of key value pairs you could trun your array into a `Dictionary<string,string>` and serialise that using DataContractJsonSerializer.  However you would end up with something like:

```
{
    {
    "Key":"name1",
    "Value":"value1"
    },
    {
    "Key":"name2",
    "Value":"value2"
    }
}
```

I.e. an array of key value pairs.

Comment: Nice one. I've constructed and new helper .net class with a property which returns a Dictionary.
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, string> Fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();